# How to get the HWND of a Combobox in another window?

Tags: c++, combobox

How can I get the HWND of the Combobox using C++ in another third party application?

MSDN has a function called [GetDlgItem()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645481%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) but the 2nd parameter requires the ID of the control. There is the function [GetDlgCtrlID()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645478%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to get that control ID but that requires the HWND of the Combobox.

Would I have to use UIspy or Spy++ to retrieve information to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

Yes use a spy tool to get the control ID. GetDlgItem also requires the HWND of the control's parent dialog.

Comment: The control ID is listed as "FFFFFF22" for one of the combobox. I tried converting that from hexadecimal to decimal (4294967074) and using GetDlgItem(hwnd, 4294967074); //where hwnd is the parent HWND but unfortunately the return value was 0, what did I do wrong?